# Does it make sense to apply bio-oil products such as vitamin E (oil), Aloe vera, etc. on the scar to minimize scarring?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery, vitamin-e, aloe-vera

I have 1-month old scar on my face. Now I am using silicone gel against scars. On the internet I found that in such cases, it will also be useful to apply such products as vitamin E (liquid form), aloe vera gel, petroleum jelly, coconut oil, lavender oil, linseed oil, honey and other products containing bio-oil.

---

I have a question. Does it make sense to apply these substances on the scar to minimize the scarring? Does it actually work against scars? Some sources write about a significant positive effect against scarring while others state that such products have not been shown to be of much benefit.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide the site from which your research was based.